# Ideas for making an iOS compatible Javascript keyboard

Tags: javascript, css, ios, html, dhtml

Does anyone have any ideas about how to make a Javascript virtual keyboard for iOS? It must be selectible, nice looking, clipboard compatible... etc.

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in keyboard?

Comment: It doesn't work with an API I am using.

Comment: Ok, so if you can't fond the correct tires for your car, you'll prefer to re-invent the wheel? Won't you change your tire-dealer?

Comment: There is no other option for tires. (By the way, my tire is Codemirror)

Comment: Plus, the mobile keyboard layout is terrible for programming. I was thinking that I could replace the unused programming keys on the first page for each language, i.e. for HTML take out the '`,`' and the '`.`' and put in `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started some work on this a little while ago. See [iOS/Android browser: showing a zoomed preview of button on touchmove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045817/ios-android-browser-showing-a-zoomed-preview-of-button-on-touchmove) and this example http://ampersand.no.de/iOSkeyboard. The last keyboard is the iOS one. It uses jQuery for DOM access, but could easily be changed to get rid of this dependency.

Maybe you could expand on this to get where you need to be?

Comment: Thanks - this is a great start! Do you have any ideas on using the caret to insert text?

Comment: You'd have to add right/left arrow keys that will re-position the caret. Take a look at how the backspace works as a start. I wouldn't recommend using `<input>` elements, because focusing on them will activate the native KB (unless you do `event.preventDefault()` on the `focus` event).